# CouchDB: Performance dynamic and static content

Tags: performance, dynamic, static, couchdb

in my CouchDB, I maintain 1000's of documents, where each document
has dynamic and static content.
Let's say some documents with random static content and dynamic content
like "last access date", "number of access", etc.
The dynamic content is altered by server side routines for each read
access. The static content is never changed after its creation.

My questions are:

1. Is the performance of reading the content influenced, if I store the dynamic and static content in separate documents?
2. I've multiple views on the static content of the document. Are the views
   updated if I change the dynamic content?

Thanks in advance,
Sascha

Answer (score 2):

Yes and yes.

I mean: if objects have been updated after last call to the views, the next time you will call a view, map functions will be applied to the objects you changed (and reduce functions will be applied to the "reduce branches" that have been invalidated).

Test your solution in real settings. If this update is a problem for your application performance, then, yes, it would be probably a good idea to save your more dynamic contents in different documents.

Note however that this is probably necessary only in the case where there are a lot of updated documents between two view calls, or in the case where the processing of a single document is very long or emits many keys.

Answer (score 2):

Further to Aurélien's answer, if you decide to split the 'static' and 'dynamic' content you should consider doing so by creating a simple log document for each access, rather than having a single 'dynamic' counterpart for each 'static' document. This would reduce contention on reads. You could then use a reduce function to group the data for viewing and periodically you could gather the logs for a particular 'static' document into a single log entry.